# If the local minimal is not regular point the necessary condition for constraint problem needs not to hold

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $D $ be the surface determined by set of equation $\{x\in \Bbb{R}^n \mid h_1(x) = h_2(x) = ...=h_k(x) = 0\}$ where $h_i$ are smooth function, let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ be smooth function, if $f$ attains minimum at the point $x^*$ under the constraint $D$.  If assume further that $x^* $ is not regular point of $D$, then the minimum point must satisfies the necessary condition that :

$$\nabla f(x^*) \in \text{span}(\nabla h_i(x^*))$$

Is there some example that if $x^*$ is not regular point of the surface $D$ then the condition does not hold?

Comment: This condition called  constraint qualification https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Example_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f(x) = x_1 + x_2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & h_1 (x) = (x_1 - 1)^2 + x_2^2 - 1 = 0 \\
& & &h_2(x) = (x_1 -2)^2 +x_2^2 -4 =0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*} with local minimum $x^* = (0, 0)$. We observe that the cost gradient at $x^*$, i.e., $\nabla f(x^*) = (1, 1)$, can not be expressed as a linear combination of the constraint gradient at $x^*$, i.e., $\nabla h_1 (x^*) = (-2, 0)$ and $\nabla h_2 (x^*) = (-4, 0)$. So $\nabla f(x^*) \notin \text{span} \{\nabla h_1 (x), \nabla h_2 (x) \}$ and there are no Lagrange multipliers.